# How to convert text to 3d

Tags: php, html

so we have a new client at work who is requestion 3d text for his website. I know I could do it in corel draw but I was wondering if there is a way to do it on the fly. ( Dynamically )

I'm using php and html. Is there a php function?

Answer (score 1):

No. Such a function does not exists in the PHP language.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.onlinecreations.com.au/free_software/paintstar/tutorial-3d-text.php

That isnt php or html...But then I dont know any php or html command that can create 3d from text..

Answer (score -4):

You're looking for strto3d()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strto3d.php